# reload page and change css code

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have i form inside a div , the div is hidden to display it i should click on a a href button ,  when i click on the submit button inside the hidden div  the page is reloaded and then the div return to be hidden , what i want to do , is something that could allow me to keep the div visible and and not let it be hidden again when i reload the page , what could i do ?
this is the css class of my div

```
    .inscription
    {  
      background-color:#ffffff;
      width:950px;
      height:670px;
      position:relative;
      display:none;
      margin-top:50px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **display:block**

```
 .inscription
        {  
          background-color:#ffffff;
          width:950px;
          height:670px;
          position:relative;
          margin-top:50px;
          display:block;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you need preventDefault()

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
     //Do something
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

clicked href will not take the browser to a new URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to submit the form without reloading it.  Here is an example:

```
// event handler for when the form is submitted
$("#form").submit(function(){       
   var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
   var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: formURL,   
      data: postData  
   });
   return false;  // when false is returned, the page won't reload
}
```